# Pandas excel columns name and datatype to json

Tags: python, pandas

I have one excel file that I am reading through  pandas, I am able to get the columns and it's type with below code

```
import pandas as pd

def read_from_gs():
    #print('read : ' ,path)
    #df = pd.read_csv(path, sep=separator)
    df = pd.read_excel('sample/sam.xlsx')
    #print(df.dtypes.to_json())
    print((df.dtypes.to_json()) )
    # data_json = data_frame.to_json()
    return df

read_from_gs()
```

I was to able to get thie df.dtype.tolist, but I am not able to get the column name and its type in json format like

```
{"name": "string/object","marks":"int32"}
```

> df.dtypes.to_json() throwing error
>
> OverflowError: Maximum recursion level reached
>
> output of dtypes
>
> area              int64 area_title       object area_type
> int64 naics            object naics_title      object i_group
> object own_code          int64 occ_code         object occ_title
> object o_group          object tot_emp          object emp_prse
> object jobs_1000       float64 loc_quotient    float64 pct_total
> object h_mean           object a_mean           object mean_prse
> object h_pct10          object h_pct25          object h_median
> object h_pct75          object h_pct90          object a_pct10
> object
>
> and type is <class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>

Any help

Thanks

Comment: What does `df.dtypes` look like?

Comment: Maybe, try the `to_dict()` function ?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that `json` module can not recognize `pandas/numpy` dtypes like `numpy.dtypes.Int64DType`, `numpy.dtypes.ObjectDType` etc. on encoding phase.
Use `default_handler=str` workaround:

```
df.dtypes.to_json(default_handler=str)
```

Comment: Thanks, one question I am seeing even if column has date value only its showing object

Comment: @Md.ParvezAlam, "date value" belongs to values, but you are converting `dtypes`

Comment: but for integer and float it gives the correct result